# MATLAB programming : optimize my code

Tags: matlab

Is there a way here to write more efficient, more generic code?

As the value return doesn't change, do I need a switch here?

```
function result = whichValue(value)
    switch value
        case 'green_ok'
            result = 'green&ok';
        case 'green_ko'
            result = 'green&ko';
        case 'green_check'
            result = 'green&check';                    
    end
end
```

Comment: Can you clarify the purpose of this function? Are you just looking to switch all '_' to '&'?

Comment: the objective is to put strings in a function then call the function with each string : example if I'm expectig to see 'green&ko' , I call whichValue('green_ko')

Comment: Do you mean you'll pass a variable containing a string, and you want to know which value is stored in your variable, but changing the '_' to '&'? If so, I think a 'more efficient' code would be to avoid writing a separate function and consider trying to replace within your variable, possibly storing as a new variable if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html?refresh=true):

```
value_split = strsplit(value, '_');
result = [value_split{1}, '&', value_split{2}]
```

Comment: it's not ok with value_split{2}

Comment: value_split is a 1x1cell

Comment: as per problem description : when I call the function : whichValue('green_ok')

Comment: the value is a string , the objective of the function is to put strings in one function then call it with each value

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a poor way of doing things, but seems to work for your examples:

```
result=value
value(value=='_')='&'
```

Comment: @lola my suggestion, not your code, sorry for the confusion! Using logical indexing like I have done seems strange for operations on strings, but it does seem to work!